# Make a div float whenever the bottom of it goes out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm able to add and remove classes that make a div float and unfloat, but I'm restricted to having to enter a scroll amount until the classes gets added.

What I'd like to have, is for the class to be added when the bottom of the div goes out of view, or past the viewport.

Likewise, for the class to be removed when the bottom of the div (in it's original place) can be seen again - although I'm not sure about this, as the div will always be visible now.. as it's being floated.

http://jsfiddle.net/r440tggy/

```
var header = $("#request-consultation");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 750) {
        header.addClass("fixed-bottom-left");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("fixed-bottom-left");
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to use offset.. will give an example how you do this soon.. within an hour

Comment: `position:sticky` can be useful in browsers that support it http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Which are three. No where near enough for a reliable solution, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the element position before the scroll event makes sure that rendering problems don't happen.

You just need to get the elements position from the top, add the height and do a check against that.

```js
var header = $("#request-consultation");
var element = header.offset().top + header.outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= element) {
    header.addClass("fixed-bottom-left");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("fixed-bottom-left");
  }
});
```

```css
#request-consultation {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.fixed-bottom-left {
  float: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="request-consultation">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
    tincidunt blandit.</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae dolor ligula. Cras at purus eget ante gravida rhoncus. Aliquam dictum, odio a fermentum mollis, lorem ante sagittis est, sed pharetra risus leo sed augue. Aenean sed massa quis elit
  tincidunt blandit. Proin elementum cursus pretium. Mauris tempor arcu nec sem ullamcorper dictum. Nulla eu tellus vitae justo aliquet maximus. Fusce id mauris sed sapien fermentum interdum. Nunc laoreet ligula sed quam scelerisque, at faucibus elit
  euismod. Donec et est imperdiet, pulvinar augue cursus, tincidunt eros. Donec nec ornare mi. Duis eget lacus sed nisl hendrerit elementum sed vel metus. Integer vel lacus at ex lobortis dignissim non in tortor. Vestibulum sit amet metus non velit varius
  tristique. Pellentesque in lorem sed mi efficitur elementum. Suspendisse eu fermentum neque, et rhoncus lectus.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The class doesn't change when the div finally goes out of view though, it seems to change at a random point as you scroll (not so random though, as it does exactly the same regardless of window size). What's the logic for the break point?

Comment: @Lee apologies, it was because i used `position()` instead of `offset()`. Try now.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask to expand this? As this also happens when viewing on a mobile, which looks a bit ugly. Is there a way to add a condition that when viewed on a screen 768px or lower, move the float outside of view, and add a div that toggles the slide?

Comment: That will require a mixture of css media queries, more divs and new js functions. Give and give it a go yourself first and see if you can complete it, if not then jump on a chat session with me and Ill see if i can help.